# Locking on an object?

Tags: node.js, locking

I'm very new to Node.js and I'm sure there's an easy answer to this, I just can't find it :(

I'm using the filesystem to hold 'packages' (folders with a status extensions 'mypackage.idle') Users can perform actions on these which would cause the status to go to something like 'qa', or 'deploying' etc... If the server is accepting lots of requests and multiple requests come in for the same package how would I check the status and then perform an action, which would change the status, guaranteeing that another request didn't alter it before/during the action took place?

so in c# something like this

```
lock (someLock) { checkStatus(); performAction(); }
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If checkStatus() and performAction() are synchronous functions called one after another, then as others mentioned earlier: their exectution will run uninterupted till completion.
However, I suspect that in reality both of these functions are asynchoronous, and the realistic case of composing them is something like:

```
function checkStatus(callback){
  doSomeIOStuff(function(something){
    callback(something == ok);
  });
}

checkStatus(function(status){
  if(status == true){
    performAction();
  }
});
```

The above code is subject to race conditions, as when doSomeIOStuff is being perfomed instead of waiting for it new request can be served.

You may want to check https://www.npmjs.com/package/rwlock library.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit misleading. There are many script languages that are suppose to be single threaded, but when sharing data from the same source this creates a problem. NodeJs might be single threaded when you are running a single request, but when you have multiple requests trying to access the same data, it just behaves as it creates kind of the same problem as if you were running a multithreaded language.

There is already an answer about this here : [Locking on an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145749/locking-on-an-object)

```
WATCH sentinel_key
GET value_of_interest
if (value_of_interest = FULL)
    MULTI
    SET sentinel_key = foo
    EXEC
    if (EXEC returned 1, i.e. succeeded)
        do_something();
    else
        do_nothing();
else
    UNWATCH
```

Comment: link provided is an exercise in recursion.

Comment: Ambiguous answer. If by "data" this is referring to filesystems, databases, and external processes then yes locking is still a problem. If this is referring to in-process data structures then locking is not a problem, as described by other answers here.

Comment: @RichardMarr Of course it is. If you have a function `T` that chains 10 asynchronous operations that alter shared data structure (all inside Node.js process) then what will happen if you run `T` twice in a row? There's a race condition.

Comment: @freakish locking isn't a solution to race conditions. Race conditions are when memory is written in an unexpected order. Locking doesn't correct the order of writes, it just provides a way to make each thread wait for the previous thread to finish writing. The outcome of running `T` twice in parallel on Node will be exactly the same if you ran it in two threads on the JVM with appropriate threading and locking. Both would exhibit a race condition.

Comment: @RichardMarr Seriously? I don't allow to fire `T` until the previous call to `T` finalizes whatever it does. This is exactly what lock does by definition. Stating that this doesn't fix the inconsistency issue is madness.

Comment: @freakish not up for discussing it with you if you're going to get personal

Comment: @RichardMarr Where exactly did I get personal? I've never said anything about you. I'm only talking about the level of arguments. But I do understand such reaction: after all it's impossible to defend "lockin isn't a solution" statement.

Comment: @freakish, questioning my sanity is an ad hominem attack, it has no part in a rational discussion, and is offensive. Similarly, stating that I have no case because I don't wish to be abused by you is equally fallacious. You can enjoy the rest of this discussion on your own, I'm off to have lunch in the sun.

Comment: @RichardMarr Whatever, dude. I'm neither soo sensitive nor childish to argue about words. I'm not responsible for what you feel. But if you think that I'm wrong, then please correct me and stop hiding behind meta arguments. Have a good lunch.

Comment: @freakish okay 'dude' call me childish and sensitive if you like, to avoid the self-admission that your comments were rude. You seem to think that the solution to race conditions is to avoid all parallelism by blocking execution. That's a solution but not an elegant or performant one. I, on the other hand was talking about `locking` which is a widely used solution to `resource contention` (along with queues and mutexes) and doesn't solve race conditions because the first thread to lock a resource still may not be the thread you expected: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29

Comment: @freakish have you read up on locking yet? Still convinced it's "impossible to defend" that locking isn't a solution to race conditions? While you're thinking, here's a lovely poster you can print and keep https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/

Comment: @RichardMarr You admitted yourself that it **is** a solution. I've never said it is elegant (whatever that means) or performant - that's a different topic. Also I did not say that it is the only possible solution (there are lock-free algorithms after all). But it does solve the inconsistency problem and you cannot deny it.

Comment: @RichardMarr I'm not sure what you mean by "it doesn't solve race conditions because the first thread to lock a resource still may not be the thread you expected". It should not matter which thread acquires the lock. Otherwise you are screwed beyond help since (generally) it is impossible to predict the order.

Comment: @freakish blocking concurrency is a solution to race conditions in the same way that not having a car is a solution to avoiding car accidents. You don't use concurrency for a giggle, you use it because you need the performance benefit or it's unavoidable in a given context, so your 'solution' is not generally applicable. That said, my original comment (the one that you objected to) was about the fact that Node doesn't need to use `locking` to solve `resource contention` on in-process memory. Your comments are off-topic

Comment: @RichardMarr My comments are off-topic? Is it solution or not? Why are you continously using arguments that I didn't argue against? I'm talking about consistency, you are talking about performance - who's really off-topic? Besides locking **is** a generally used pattern whenever you put consistency above performance. Every database uses locks. Still not generally applicable? And if you think that Node doesn't need to use locking, then please tell me how you solve the original `T` function problem without locking.

Comment: @RichardMarr Where did I talk about **external** resources? What do you think a database is? Whenever you access file system or memory with Node.js you are accessing a database. I'm looking forward to your database implementation without locks. Good luck. Now the level of conversation with you is at least bad. You are putting words in my mouth I didn't say, you are avoiding difficult questions and you are hiding behind meta arguments. And I don't care who wins, I only care about the truth. And the truth is that there are things that you can't do without locks.

Comment: -1 All this arguing, and nobody even mentions that @lac_dev answered a node.js question with an example written in CLIPS :) WTF

Comment: Reading over this, as a professional and educator, it's annoying to see @RichardMarr state with false authority that locking isn't a solution to race conditions. While it is possible to use database sharding, functional and pass-by-copy programming techniques to minimize use of shared resources, ultimately any truly concurrent design with state has a *few* and the challenge is to *minimize them*. The comment that using locks to prevent concurrency  is akin to avoid driving at all to avoid accidents -- pure nonsense. Traffic lights are *exactly* locks.

Comment: @Basezen this argument was probably my least shining moment on SO, and clearly a breakdown in communication. Two people interpreting each others answers in the least favourable light and trying to correct them. I'm sure that you as a professional and an educator know better than to join in and stir it all up again.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is lock on an external object, for instance, a sequence in a database such as Oracle or Redis.

http://redis.io/commands

For example, I am using cluster with node.js (I have 4 cores) and I have a node.js function and each time I run through it, I increment a variable. I basically need to lock on that variable so no two threads use the same value of that variable.

check this out [How to create a distributed lock with Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736102/how-to-create-a-distributed-lock-with-redis)

and this https://engineering.gosquared.com/distributed-locks-using-redis

I think you can run with this idea if you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are making asynchronous calls with callbacks, this means multiple clients could potentially make the same, or related requests, and receive responses in different orders. This is definitely a case where locking is useful. You won't be 'locking a thread' in the traditional sense, but merely ensuring asynchronous calls, and their callbacks are made in a predictable order. The async-lock package looks like it handles this scenario.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-lock

Answer (score -2):

warning, node.js change semantic if you add a log entry beucause logging is IO bound.

if you change from

```
qa_action_performed = false
function handle_request() {
  if (check_status() == STATUS_QA && !qa_action_performed) {
    qa_action_performed = true
    perform_action()
  }
}
```

to

```
qa_action_performed = false
function handle_request() {
  if (check_status() == STATUS_QA && !qa_action_performed) {
    console.log("my log stuff");
    qa_action_performed = true
    perform_action()
  }
}
```

more than one thread can execute perform_action().

Comment: Can you provide more information about that? Doesn't seem to be the case from my sample code. 

process.nextTick(function(){ console.log('NEXT TICK'); });
for ( var i = 0; i < 10000; i++ ){ console.log(i) }

Comment: This is not correct. `console.log` is a blocking function.  Even if it were not, the worst that could happen is the console output would be jumbled.

Answer (score -4):

You don't have to worry about synchronization with Node.js since it's single threaded with an event loop. This is one of the advantage of the architecture that Node.js use.

Nothing will be executed between `checkStatus()` and `performAction()`.

Answer (score -7):

There are no locks in node.js -- because you shouldn't need them. There's only one thread (the event loop) and your code is never interrupted unless you perform an asynchronous action like I/O. Hence your code should never block. You can't do any parallel code execution.

That said, your code could look something like this:

```
qa_action_performed = false
function handle_request() {
  if (check_status() == STATUS_QA && !qa_action_performed) {
    qa_action_performed = true
    perform_action()
  }
}
```

Between check_status() and perform_action() no other thread can interrupt because there is no I/O. As soon as you enter the if clause and set qa_action_performed = true, no other code will enter the if block and hence perform_action() is never executed twice, even if perform_action() takes time performing I/O.

Comment: nice! thank you. So even though http.createServer could asynchronously handle hundreds of requests per second only one of those requests could enter the 'handle_request' function above at a time?

Comment: As the code stands above, yes. If you have async I/O in check_status(), e.g., because you need to access a DB or the file system, you would use a callback, like check_status(function(result) { if (result == STATUS_QA && ... }). In this case multiple requests can enter handle_request(), but with !qa_action_performed you are still protected against multiple execution sof perform_action().

Comment: Nice! exactly what I was after. Thanks for your response/info on this :)

Comment: I find this "no parallel code execution" meme in Node.js to be perplexing. If you have two tasks (T1 and T2) and each one requires, say, 10 asynchronous callbacks to be chained together, then some callbacks for T2 will execute while T1 waits for an async operation to finish. Is this not T1 and T2 executing in "parallell"? If T1 and T2 have some shared, non-reentrant resource, do they not need to lock that resource to ensure these two tasks don't corrupt it?

Comment: -1 for `because you shouldn't need them`. You absolutely do need them (as mentioned by @mehaase) unless your app is nothing more then a calculator.

Comment: -1 for the same.  How could you not need access to semaphores in an environment where asynchronous IO operations are eligible to interrupt each other as they execute? (see @mehaase and @freakish)

Comment: This is a weird "both right, but about very different things" scenario. In the (unrealistically) simple way the question was asked and answered, it is correct that straight computation-only code cannot get pre-empted in Node.js as it does in, say, C with OS-supported Pthreads. So the two environment shouldn't be confused. However, in any realistic scenario, check_status() needs to do some kind of I/O to be reliable. Imagine your node process crashes; The dependence of `check_status()` on memory-only data has destroyed your system state irrevocably.