# How to create a distributed lock with Redis?

Tags: redis, locking

On the redis documentation, I found a primitive lock can be implemented via SETNX:

http://redis.io/commands/setnx

> - C4 sends SETNX lock.foo in order to acquire the lock
> - The crashed client C3 still holds it, so Redis will reply with 0 to C4.
> - C4 sends GET lock.foo to check if the lock expired. If it is not, it will sleep for some time and retry from the start.
> - Instead, if the lock is expired because the Unix time at lock.foo is older than the current Unix time, C4 tries to perform:
>
>   > GETSET lock.foo
> - Because of the GETSET semantic, C4 can check if the old value stored at key is still an expired timestamp. If it is, the lock was acquired.
> - If another client, for instance C5, was faster than C4 and acquired the lock with the GETSET operation, the C4 GETSET operation will return a non expired timestamp. C4 will simply restart from the first step. Note that even if C4 set the key a bit a few seconds in the future this is not a problem.

However, as some users commented, using a UNIX timestamp as the expiration requires the client 's and server's time to be perfectly synchronized. Is there a better alternative to create a global/distributed lock in Redis?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `SET` instead of `SETNX`. `SET` accepts arguments for expiration time in seconds and milliseconds instead of UNIX timestamp value.

The old SETNX based pattern is documented only for historical reasons.

From `SETNX` [description](http://redis.io/commands/setnx):

> NOTE: Starting with Redis 2.6.12 it is possible to create a much
>   simpler locking primitive using the SET command to acquire the lock,
>   and a simple Lua script to release the lock. The pattern is documented
>   in the SET command page.

Answer (score 7):

Using **redis >= 2.6** the LUA script solution would be great. Lua script always executed atomically so:

```
--lockscript, parameters: lock_key, lock_timeout
local lock = redis.call('get', KEYS[1])
if not lock then    
    return redis.call('setex', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], "locked");
end
return false
```

The another solution based on new options of `SET` command

```
SET lock_key "locked" EX lock_timeout NX
```

Using **redis < 2.6** the pattern with multi can be used:

```
MULTI
SETNX tmp_unique_lock some_value
EXPIRE tmp_unique_lock
RENAMENX tmp_unique_lock real_lock
EXEC
```

Comment: I liked `SET EX NX` solution and gem'ed it out to a cool gem - [simple_redis_lock](https://github.com/nitzanav/simple_redis_lock)

Answer (score 1):

The new arguments for [SET](http://redis.io/commands/set) are enough for setting the lock, but these only work on Redis >= v2.6.12 you also need to think about how the lock will be unset and expire etc.

I've written a post on our Engineering blog about [distributed locks using Redis](https://engineering.gosquared.com/distributed-locks-using-redis). It covers scripting on how to set and release the lock reliably, with validation and deadlock prevention. I also include a module written in Node.js you can use for locking straight out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I gem'ed out the `SET EX NX` solution that misterion mentioned to a cool gem - [simple_redis_lock](https://github.com/nitzanav/simple_redis_lock)

The code is simple and looks like this:

```
def lock(key, timeout)
  if @redis.set(key, Time.now, nx: true, px: timeout)
    begin
      yield
    ensure
      release key
    end
  end
end
```