# Safely setting keys with StackExchange.Redis while allowing deletes

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to use Redis as a cache that sits in front of an SQL database. At a high level I want to implement these operations:

1. Read value from Redis, if it's not there then generate the value via querying SQL, and push it in to Redis so we don't have to compute that again.
2. Write value to Redis, because we just made some change to our SQL database and we know that we might have already cached it and it's now invalid.
3. Delete value, because we know the value in Redis is now stale, we suspect nobody will want it, but it's too much work to recompute now. We're OK letting the next client who does operation #1 compute it again.

My challenge is understanding how to implement #1 and #3, if I attempt to do it with StackExchange.Redis. If I naively implement #1 with a simple read of the key and push, it's entirely possible that between me computing the value from SQL and pushing it in that any number of other SQL operations may have happened and also tried to push their values into Redis via #2 or #3. For example, consider this ordering:

1. Client #1 wants to do operation #1 [Read] from above. It tries to read the key, sees it's not there.
2. Client #1 calls to SQL database to generate the value.
3. Client #2 does something to SQL and then does operation #2 [Write] above. It pushes some newly computed value into Redis.
4. Client #3 comes a long, does some other operation in SQL, and wants to do operation #3 [Delete] to Redis knowing that if there's something cached there, it's no longer valid.
5. Client #1 pushes its (now stale) value to Redis.

So how do I implement my operation #1? Redis offers a `WATCH` primitive that makes this fairly easy to do against the bare metal where I would be able to observe other things happened on the key from Client #1, but [it's not supported by StackExchange.Redis because of how it multiplexes commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789720/how-to-do-basic-watch-with-stackexchange-redis). It's conditional operations aren't quite sufficient here, since if I try saying "push only if key doesn't exist", that doesn't prevent the race as I explained above. Is there a pattern/best practice that is used here? This seems like a fairly common pattern that people would want to implement.

One idea I do have is I can use a separate key that gets incremented each time I do some operation on the main key and then can use StackExchange.Redis' conditional operations that way, but that seems kludgy.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like question about right cache invalidation strategy rather then question about Redis. Why i think so - Redis **WATCH**/**MULTI** is kind of *optimistic locking strategy* and this kind of
locking not suitable for most of cases with cache where db read query can be a problem which solves with cache. In your operation #3 description you write:

> It's too much work to recompute now. We're OK letting the next client who does operation #1 compute it again.

So we can continue with `read update` case as update strategy. Here is some more questions, before we continue:

1. That happens when 2 clients starts to perform operation #1? Both of them can do not find value in Redis and perform SQL query and next both of then write it to Redis. So we should have garanties that just one client would update cache?
2. How we can be shure in the right sequence of writes (operation 3)?

### Why not optimistic locking

[Optimistic concurrency control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) assumes that multiple transactions can frequently complete without interfering with each other. While running, transactions use data resources without acquiring locks on those resources. Before committing, each transaction verifies that no other transaction has modified the data it has read. If the check reveals conflicting modifications, the committing transaction rolls back and can be restarted.

You can read about OCC transactions phases in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) but in few words:

> If there is no conflict - you update your data. If there is a conflict, resolve it, typically by aborting the transaction and restart it if still need to update data.

Redis WATCH/MULTY is kind of optimistic locking so they can't help you - you do not know about your cache key was modified before try to work with them.

### What works?

Each time your listen somebody told about locking - after some words you are listen about compromises, performance and consistency vs availability. The last pair is most important.

In most of high loaded system availability is winner. Thats this means for caching? Usualy such case:

1. Each cache key hold some metadata about value - state, version and life time. The last one is not Redis TTL - usually if your key should be in cache for X time, life time 
   in metadata has X + Y time, there Y is some time to garantie process update.
2. You never delete key directly - you need just update state or life time.
3. Each time your application read data from cache if should make decision - if data has state "valid" - use it. If data has state "invalid" try to update or use absolete data.

How to update on read(the quite important is this "hand made" mix of optimistic and pessisitic locking):

1. Try set pessimistic locking (in Redis with SETEX - [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736102/how-to-create-a-distributed-lock-with-redis/20741241#20741241)).
2. If failed - return absolete data (rememeber we still need availability).
3. If success perform SQL query and write in to cache.
4. Read version from Redis again and compare with version readed previously.
5. If version same - mark as state as "valid".
6. Release lock.

How to invalidate (your operations #2, #3):

1. Increment cache version and set state "invalid".
2. Update life time/ttl if need it.

### Why so difficult

1. We always can get and return value from cache and rarely have situatiuon with cache miss. So we do not have cache invalidation cascade hell then many process try to update
   one key.
2. We still have ordered key updates.
3. Just one process per time can update key.

### I have queue!

Sorry, you have not said before - I would not write it all. If have queue all becomes more simple:

1. Each modification operation should push job to queue.
2. Only async worker should execute SQL and update key.
3. You still need use "state" (valid/invalid) for cache key to separete application logic with cache.

### Is this is answer?

Actualy yes and no in same time. This one of possible solutions. Cache invalidation is much complex problem with many possible solutions - one of them 
may be simple, other - complex. In most of cases depends on real bussines requirements of concrete applicaton.