# Sharing singleton instance between multiple proccesses

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegraf

I have a telegram bot where the connection is created through a class instance.

```js
class Bot {
  public bot;

  constructor() {
    this.bot = new TelegramBot();
  }
}

export default Bot;
```

I then have another file where I create the instance of the bot and export so I can import it and use it on the other files.

```js
import bot from './bot';

const botInstance = new Bot();

export default botInstance;
```

For example, if I want to do something with this bot instance in a file:

```js
import botInstance from './botInstance';

botInstance.sendMessage(12345, 'hello!');
```

All of this is happening between different node proccesses (different files), each doing their own logic with the bot by importing the `botInstance.js` and doing stuff with it.

Ex:

`node src/proccess1.js`

`node src/queue.js`

The problem: When I run more than one proccess, they just conflict kill the bot because they are inittiating a new bot and running at the same time when I import it. Instead of initiating a single instance of the bot and sharing it, they each other create one for themselves.

My question is: how can I share the same instance with all the different proccesses/files, without creating a new instance of the class `Bot` every time.

Please, if anyone can give me some light on this. I spent a few hours trying to find a solution but I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know you can use [lockfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lockfile) and [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache) together to achieve what you want;

By this you synchronise and lock the file when some other process is using it for more information you can refer to this link
[How to Synchronize object between multiple instance of Node Js application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735992/how-to-synchronize-object-between-multiple-instance-of-node-js-application)