# Does node-cache uses locks

Tags: node.js, caching, locking

I'm trying to understand if the `node-cache` package uses locks for the cache object and can't find anything.

I tried to look at the source code and it doesn't look like it, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42961272) suggests otherwise with the quote:

> So there is Redis and node-cache for memory locks.

This cache is used in a CRUD server and I want to make sure that GET/UPDATE requests will not create a race condition on the data.

Comment: Did you just go look at [the source code](https://github.com/node-cache/node-cache) yourself?

Comment: As I said, I looked and it indeed doesn't look like it, but I was wondering if maybe there is something that I missed due to the comment of the other person, and also some minor tests that I did that did make it seem like it is locked

Comment: I don't see any evidence of locking in the code.  If two requests for the same key which is not in the cache are made one after the other, then it will launch two separate `fetch()` operations and whichever request comes back last is the one that will remain in the cache.  Probably not normally a problem, but an improved implementation could make only one request for that same key and have the second request just wait for the first request to provide the value.

Comment: Since the cache itself is all in-memory, all access to the cache is synchronous and thus regulated by Javascript's single threaded nature.  So, the only place concurrency issues could affect things in the cache code itself are when they launch an asynchronous `fetch()` operation.  There are, of course, race conditions waiting to happen in how one uses the code that accesses the data just like there are with a database interface so the calling code has to be smart about racy things.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any evidence of locking in [the code](https://github.com/node-cache/node-cache).

If two requests for the same key which is not in the cache are made one after the other, then it will launch two separate `fetch()` operations and whichever request comes back last is the one that will remain in the cache. This is probably not normally a problem, but an improved implementation could make only one request for that same key and have the second request just wait for the first request to provide the value that was already in flight.

Since the cache itself is all in-memory, all access to the cache is synchronous and thus regulated by Javascript's single threaded nature. So, the only place concurrency issues could affect things in the cache code itself are when they launch an asynchronous `fetch()` operation.

There are, of course, race conditions waiting to happen in how one uses the code that accesses the data just like there are with a database interface so the calling code has to be smart about how it uses the interface to avoid creating race conditions because of how it calls things.

Comment: @shlomita - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, you can write a unit test to confirm it.

I have written a library to fix that and also added read through method to easy the code usage:
https://github.com/KhanhPham2411/node-cache-async-lock